# Prevent Lex scanner from ever terminating the program

Tags: parsing, exit, lex

So, I discovered it is possible to cause Lex scanner to call `exit()` when instead of a file, for input, it is given a directory.  It then will print `input in flex scanner failed` and will exit the program...  This is... very unexpected behavior for a library code, to put mildly.

Thus, the question: is there any way to preclude Lex code from ever exiting the program?  I mean, there's no reason `yyparse` or `yypush_parse` or their friends not report this in their exit code... why should they terminate the whole program?  I was looking for options to specify in `*.l` file and such... but so far all web search hits suggest I just check myself for all possible conditions under which Lex will terminate the program and catch them before they get to Lex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct, and it is a bit ugly. Flex scanners die ungracefully on I/O errors, and there is no simple option to prevent that.

Flex scanners will also call `exit()` if there is a memory allocation error (including cases where buffers cannot be dynamically reallocated) and a variety of internal errors.

You can avoid the issue with I/O errors by implementing your own definition of `YY_INPUT` which doesn't call `exit()`, but there is no mechanism for the `YY_INPUT` macro to report an error, in part because there is no way for `yylex` to return an error indication to the parser. You could use some clumsy workaround like setting a flag and returning EOF (i.e. 0), but it isn't very clean.

Looking at the Flex skeleton file, it appears that you could define the macro `YY_FATAL_ERROR(msg)`, which wraps the call to `exit()`. However, it is not entirely clear what you could actually do to report the error condition. You can't just `return` because some of the invocations of `YY_FATAL_ERROR` are not in the main `yylex` function. About the only possibility I can see would be a `longjmp` (unless you're using C++, in which casr you could throw an exception).